# How can I use CSRF protection with WTForms and Pyramid?

Tags: python, pyramid, wtforms

How can I use CSRF protection with WTForms and Pyramid?

In flask, there's a WTForms module which handles this.

What would be a way to have this with Pyramid as well without creating spaghetti code implemented in main logic and with all forms?

Comment: you can use wtforms independtly of flask's implementation and implement your own CSRF protection. see this http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/1.0.2/ext.html#creating-your-own-csrf-implementation

Comment: Thanks @codegeek. I have read the page before posting this question. I don't want to have in each form definition the code for CSRF. I was wondering about implementing a more global solution into Pyramid's configuration (perhaps) like flask-WTF does. Could you advise on that?

Comment: I am not familiar with Pyramid. But seems to me that you are looking for a middleware CSRF protection that could be hooked on to your pyramid app. Basically, look at the request and check csrf and return response accordingly. You can even look at Django's middleware CSRF implementation at https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/middleware/csrf.py

Comment: Thanks @codegeek, excellent help. I shall check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSRF protection in WTForms is handled by subclasses of class `SecureForm`. You should implement a subclass of `SecureForm` that uses Pyramid's facilities to store tokens in user session and to obtain tokens as they come with a request for verification.

A good implementation to follow is the one for Flask, in [flask.ext.wtf.Form](https://github.com/lepture/flask-wtf/blob/master/flask_wtf/form.py#L37) class. This is a small class that should port to Pyramid without much effort.